# Is there any Plugins SDK for Liferay 7.2 GA1 CE edition in eclipse

Tags: liferay

Please let me know if there is any Plugins SDK for liferay 7.2 GA1 in eclipse. I am trying to migrate from liferay 6.2 to Liferay 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if there is one or not. (But as Ant isn't that fancy any more to manage today's dependencies, you shouldn't stay on the Plugins SDK anyway)

When you upgrade your code using [Liferay's assistant](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-2/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/upgrading-code-to-product-ver), it will take care of migrating your Plugins-SDK code to Liferay workspace and you should take that opportunity. In the process it will also help changing all the modified packages to their new names.

In related news: You should always use the latest GA release of your target major release. As 7.2 GA2 is out: Definitely use that. It might contain updated upgrade routines, and there's no need to suffer from known and fixed bugs.